# Getting icon to show in table row in HTML slim

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to get a tick icon to show in a table row where an account is generated in each row. There should be a conditional set that then displays the icon, however, the icon either shows as text or it says i isn't a variable for the class. Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

```
      tbody
            - @external_accounts.each do |account|
              tr
                td= account.name
                td= account.currency
                td= account.provider_code
                td= account.revenue_entity
                td= account.created_by
                td= l(account.created_at, format: :long)
                td= - if account.order == 0
                    i.fa.fa-check
                td= link_to 'Edit', edit_external_account_path(account), class: 'btn btn-default'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `=` in the cell where you want to show the check. `=` tells slim that the Ruby code produces an output to add to the buffer, so conditionals should start with `-` instead of `=`

Something like

```
tbody
  - @external_accounts.each do |account|
    tr
      ...
      td
        - if account.order == 0
          i.fa.fa-check
      ...
```